# Save JSON data on local file

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my program, I get a `JSON` format data using `JSON.stringify()`. Now I want to save this `JSON` object on a file.

My question is: how can I save the `JSON` data on a file created locally when clicking on a button on `jquery`?

My `JSON` object is like this:

```
{"tasks":[{"blockId":"startpoint4","tasktype":"startpoint","properties":[],"positionX":430,"positionY":230},{"blockId":"userTask5","tasktype":"userTask","properties":[],"positionX":630,"positionY":230}],"connections":[],"properties":[],"numberOfElements":5}
```

Comment: I wouldn't allow arbitray web pages to create files on my local machine, and fortunately JS isn't capable of doing this. Use localStorage or sessionStorage to save your data to a local machine.

Comment: can you post the code you have?

Comment: do you mean to download?

Comment: No download, but save, i'm developping a workflow modeler, so i want to allow the user to save the diagram graphic properties on local file, and then, he can to reload the diagram by loading the file saved.

Comment: My code is too large so i can't post the complete code. I want just get an example to how save a JSON data in local file.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) constructor and [URL.createObjectURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) to create a temporally anchor tag with the `download` attribute set to what ever name your downloadable file should have and then trigger a `click` event on that anchor element. This will unfortunately not work in any browser, but the support for [Blob constructor](http://caniuse.com/#search=blob) is actually pretty good.

Here is an example.

```js
var data = '{"tasks":[{"blockId":"startpoint4","tasktype":"startpoint","properties":[],"positionX":430,"positionY":230},{"blockId":"userTask5","tasktype":"userTask","properties":[],"positionX":630,"positionY":230}],"connections":[],"properties":[],"numberOfElements":5}';


document
.querySelector('#download')
.addEventListener('click', function() {

  var blob = new Blob( [ data ], {
      type: 'application/octet-stream'
  });

  var url = URL.createObjectURL( blob );
  var link = document.createElement( 'a' );
  link.setAttribute( 'href', url );
  link.setAttribute( 'download', 'data.json' );

  link.click()

  URL.revokeObjectURL(url)

})
```

```html
<button id="download">Download</button>
```

Comment: Out of all the solutions from other related questions, this is my favourite answer. Is there a reason not to use 'application/json' for the type though?

Comment: Some browser addons may try to open files with a mime type of `application/json`. To ensure that the file will be downloaded and not opened directly by the browser the `application/octet-stream` is an option.

Answer (score 1):

[twFile](http://jquery.tiddlywiki.org/twFile.html) check this jquery plugin.

that allows you to read and write to a local file.

i hope this can help you

Answer (score 0):

Use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)! It's like Cookies but the files can be bigger:

```js
var json = '{"tasks":[{"blockId":"startpoint4","tasktype":"startpoint","properties":[],"positionX":430,"positionY":230},{"blockId":"userTask5","tasktype":"userTask","properties":[],"positionX":630,"positionY":230}],"connections":[],"properties":[],"numberOfElements":5}';


localStorage.setItem("json", json);

// if you want to use it, simply use localStorage.getItem("json")

console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("json")));
```

Comment: SO is giving you an error here, but test it on your page!

Comment: Ok, but when i run this, where i'll find the generated file?